# Implement a linked list program with the following functions

Tags: c++, pointers

i am trying to implement a linked list with add, search, remove and print functions. But i keep getting errors that "search, print and file are not declared in this scope" and ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive] error. Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct node
{
    public:


    char name;
    node *next;

};

bool isEmpty(node *head);
char welcomeScreen();
void addInitialElement(node *head, node*last, char name);
void add (node *&head, node *&last, char name);
void serach (node *current);
void remove (node *&head, node *&last);
void printFile(node *current);


bool isEmpty(node *head)
{
    if(head == NULL)
        return true;
    else
        return false;

}
char welcomeScreen()
{
    char options; 

    cout <<"Address Book \n";
    cout <<"Available Commands \n";
    cout <<" add <name>. \n";
    cout <<" search <name>. \n";
    cout <<" remove <name>. \n";
    cout <<" print \n";
    cout <<" file <filename>. \n";
    cout <<" quit \n";

    cin >> options;
    return options;

}
void addInitialElement(node *head, node*last, char name)
{
    node *temp = new node;
    temp->name = name;
    temp->next = NULL;
    head = temp;
    last = temp;
}
void add (node *&head, node *&last, char name)
{
    if(isEmpty(head))
        addInitialElement(head, last,name);
    else
    {
        node *temp = new node;
        temp->name = name;
        temp->next = NULL;
        last->next = temp;
        last = temp;

    }
}
void serach (node *current)
{
    node *temp = new node;


    if (current->name == temp)  
    {
        cout << "The List Contains the Following: \n";

        while(current != NULL)
        {
            cout<< current->name <<endl;
            current = current->next;
        }
    }
} 
void remove (node *&head, node *&last)
{
    if(isEmpty(head))
        cout << "ERROR: Not found for Removal. \n";  

    else if(head == last)
    {
        delete head;
        head == NULL;
        last == NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        node *temp = head;
        head = head->next;
        delete temp;
    }
}
void printFile(node *current)
{
    if(isEmpty(current))
    cout << "NO NAME IN LIST. \n";

    else
    {
        cout << "The List Contains the Following: \n";

        while(current != NULL)
        {
            cout<< current->name <<endl;
            current = current->next;
        }
    }


}

int main()
{
    node *head = NULL;
    node *last = NULL;
    char options;
    char name;

    do{
        options = welcomeScreen();

        switch(options)
        {
        case '1': cout <<"please add a name: ";
                  cin >> name;
                  add(head, last, name);
                  break; 

        case '2' : search(head, last);
                   cin >> name;
                   break;


        case '3' : remove(head, last);
                   break;

        case '4' : print(head);
                   break;

        case '5' : file(head);
                   break;

        default: cout << "system exit \n"; 
        }

    }while(options != '6');

}
```

Comment: You have spelled `search` incorrectly in the function declaration and prototype and declared `printFile` but called `print` and `file` in main

Comment: you have declared 'name' to be of type char. That's probably not what you want.

Comment: if (current->name == temp)

Comment: Thanks for spotting that. I was able to fix that part. but i still get an IOS error for this command. if (current->name == temp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You misspelled search. Do a find / replace on "serach".
2. In case 4, you may mean to call printFile instead of print

   case '4' : printFile(head);
3. In case 5, I don't know what your intention is here, but there is no function called "file". Try searching on that word, file, and you'll see.